# Ember how to use LinkView with view helper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember, I want to create a link with an optional class. In the template, I should be able to define the binding, on which the optional class is set. The target HTML should look like this

```
<li class="completed"><a>Index</a></li> < completed
<li class="active"><a>Index</a></li> < active
<li class=""><a>Index</a></li> < in-active
```

So the active/in-active states can be achieved with the `link-to` helper;

```
{{#link-to "index" tagName="li"}}<a>Index</a>{{/link-to}}
```

However, this doesn't allow me to define the optional "complete" binding. So I'm thinking about creating a subclass of `LinkView`, which does provide said binding. So the next step would be to create said subclass, and implement the binding. However I don't feel like duplicating the `link-to` helper, and am fine with using the `view` helper. However I cannot figure out how the `view` helper is supposed to work with `LinkView`:

```
{{#view Ember.LinkView "index" }}Index{{/view}}
```

> DEPRECATION: Global lookup of Ember.LinkView from a Handlebars template is deprecated.
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
{{#view Ember.LinkView target="index" }}Index{{/view}}
```

> DEPRECATION: Global lookup of Ember.LinkView from a Handlebars template is deprecated.
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I've been reading both the source of [LinkView](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/2390ea9d26ce36c9ae987954faba4d6afb2062f7/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js) and [link-to](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/2390ea9d26ce36c9ae987954faba4d6afb2062f7/packages/ember-routing-htmlbars/lib/helpers/link-to.js), but can't figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class bindings like so

```
{{#link-to 'index' tagName='li' class="active:active completed:completed"}}<a href="#">Index</a>{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my main problem. However, can you also show how `LinkView` can be used without the helper?

Comment: if it's deprecated why would you won't to use it?

Comment: I don't believe LinkView is deprecated, merely using global lookup. For example `{{view "select" }}` instead of `Ember.Select`. The question of how to use (extended) `LinkView` correctly using the view helper?